# Trying to replace delete pointer call with std::unique_ptr call

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, unique-ptr

I am getting myself confused again with unique pointers and deletion.

I am trying to avoid the need for the `delete pWidth` line below:

```
void CCreateReportDlg::DeleteColumnWidthMap(CMapWordToPtr& rMapColumnWidth)
{
    WORD        wColumn{}, * pWidth = nullptr;

    auto sPos = rMapColumnWidth.GetStartPosition();
    while (sPos != nullptr)
    {
        rMapColumnWidth.GetNextAssoc(sPos, wColumn, reinterpret_cast<void*&>(pWidth));
        if (pWidth != nullptr)
        {
            //delete pWidth;
            std::unique_ptr<WORD*> cleanup(pWidth);
        }
    }
    rMapColumnWidth.RemoveAll();
}
```

Why is it saying this?

[image]

---

Ah, I think I now see that the `unique_ptr` is supposed to be an array of `WORD` pointers. But I only have just the one value.

#### Update

Example of how I populate the map (parameter to function):

```
void CCreateReportDlg::HideColumns(CGridCtrl* pGrid, const CDWordArray* pAryDWColumns, CMapWordToPtr& rMapColumnWidth)
{
    ASSERT(pGrid != nullptr);
    ASSERT(pAryDWColumns != nullptr);

    if (pGrid == nullptr || pAryDWColumns == nullptr)
        return;

    DeleteColumnWidthMap(rMapColumnWidth);

    const auto iSize = pAryDWColumns->GetSize();
    for (INT_PTR i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
    {
        const auto dwColumnData = pAryDWColumns->GetAt(i);
        const auto iCol = LOWORD(dwColumnData);
        const auto eImage = static_cast<CheckImageIndex>(HIWORD(dwColumnData));

        if (eImage == CheckImageIndex::Unchecked)
        {
            auto pWidth = std::make_unique<WORD>().release();
            ASSERT(pWidth != nullptr);
            if (pWidth != nullptr)
            {
                *pWidth = pGrid->GetColumnWidth(iCol);
                rMapColumnWidth.SetAt(iCol, pWidth);
            }
            pGrid->SetColumnWidth(iCol, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably meant to be `std::unique_ptr<WORD[]>` (I don't know how you allocate) Consider using `std::map<WORD, std::vector<WORD>> map;`, or maybe a 2-d vector will do, such as `std::vector<std::vector<WORD>> vec;`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani See updated question. I am willing to consider a new container to simpolify this process. I don't think it even needs to be a pointer to WORD any more.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani It just has to be a WORD (column index) mapping to a WORD (column width).

Comment: It looks like all you need is `std::unordered_map<WORD, WORD>`; or, if you want to stay with MFC classes, `CMap<WORD, WORD, WORD, WORD>`. It's not necessary to allocate single `WORD`s on the heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{std::unique_ptr<WORD> cleanup(pWidth);}` for deleting `pWidth = std::make_unique<WORD>().release();`

But `std::map<int,int>` (or `unordered_map`) is a much better than `CMapWordToPtr`, you don't need to store a pointer here.

You should be able to simplify your function like this:

```
void HideColumns(CGridCtrl* pGrid, 
    std::vector<DWORD> &pAryDWColumns, std::map<int,int> &rMapColumnWidth)
{
    //clear the map, it doesn't need separate function
    rMapColumnWidth.clear();

    for (auto dword : pAryDWColumns)
    {
        const auto iCol = LOWORD(dword);
        const auto eImage = static_cast<CheckImageIndex>(HIWORD(dword));
        if (eImage == CheckImageIndex::Unchecked)
        {
            rMapColumnWidth[iCol] = pGrid->GetColumnWidth(iCol);
            pGrid->SetColumnWidth(iCol, 0);
        }
        pGrid->SetColumnWidth(iCol, 0);
    }
}

...
for (auto e : map)
    TRACE("%d\n", e);
```

By the way, in another question I think I recommended using `std::unique_ptr` to turn off some Code Analysis messages. You should ignore that advice. Either stick with `new/delete` or use STL classes which have automatic memory management.

You can still use `std::unique_ptr` in some special cases, for example when passing data to APIs or some MFC functions.

Comment: I have used the `std::unique_ptr` in a few places now so I won't change then just yet. It was mainly for reading font data or time data etc. from the registry. As for this actual method, I have aadapted it to use a `std::unordered_map` as per your initial suggestion. It is much simpler indeed and I have been able to remove all the "Delete" calls and reploace with "Clear()" where needed. But the CDWordArray current gets serialized to a CArchive so I don't want to break that.

Comment: Yes, `unique_ptr` may be necessary in some places, for example when passing data to API.